# Hide 50% of rows with low value with MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, random

I have a table with three columns:

- Description (string)
- Value (integer from 1-3)
- Date

I want to build a select which returns:

- 100% of rows with value 3
- 50% of rows with value 2
- 25% of rows with value 1

Ordered by date. „Hiding“ rows with value 1 or 2 could be random but doesn’t have to (e.g. „hide“ every second row with value 2)

It this possible with one query and without additional PHP scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use analytic functions with a random ordering to identify the first N% of each value type.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(Value = 2) OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) / SUM(Value = 2) OVER () pct_2,
        SUM(Value = 1) OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) / SUM(Value = 1) OVER () pct_1
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Value = 1 AND pct_1 > 0.25 OR Value = 2 AND pct_2 > 0.5 OR Value = 3;
```